# Databricks / pyspark write to table from notebook in .5 to 1 second?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

Trying to mimic real-time data flow in Databricks.

Created a small catalog/table of 4 columns (Strings and timestamp types) with around 10-15 rows.

In notebook writing a DataFrame out to the data lake takes around 2-4 seconds.

```
start_time = time.time()
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("my_catalog.default.people")
print(f"Execution time: {time.time() - start_time}")
```

Can this be done faster ?

```
Execution time: 4.000189781188965
Execution time: 3.988417387008667
Execution time: 3.1716957092285156
Execution time: 3.014812469482422
Execution time: 3.2062861919403076
Execution time: 3.0067527294158936
Execution time: 3.4099199771881104
Execution time: 3.850445032119751
Execution time: 2.9314992427825928
Execution time: 3.91131329536438
Execution time: 3.189704656600952
Execution time: 3.152013063430786
Execution time: 3.8201324939727783
```

Tried changing the compute cluster used but does't seem to make much difference.

Is it at all possible to have  writes execute in .5 or 1 second ?

**EDIT**

Thanks for suggested approaches.
Turns out *insertInto()* was fastest.

```
f.write.mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").partitionBy("State").saveAsTable("my_catalog.default.people")
```

```
Execution time: 3.6641693115234375
Execution time: 2.659508466720581
Execution time: 2.476632833480835
Execution time: 3.2177398204803467
Execution time: 2.871180772781372
Execution time: 2.7422285079956055
Execution time: 2.6786444187164307
Execution time: 2.4019155502319336
Execution time: 2.35744571685791
Execution time: 2.914047956466675
Execution time: 2.9255459308624268
```

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").partitionBy("State").saveAsTable("gary_catalog.default.people")
```

```
Execution time: 5.001131057739258
Execution time: 4.254853010177612
Execution time: 3.0310797691345215
Execution time: 3.1501426696777344
Execution time: 2.8274784088134766
Execution time: 3.0787553787231445
Execution time: 3.2053287029266357
Execution time: 3.416199207305908
Execution time: 3.18636417388916
```

```
df.write.option("overwriteSchema", "true").insertInto("gary_catalog.default.people",overwrite=True)
```

```
Execution time: 2.0196948051452637
Execution time: 2.0020039081573486
Execution time: 2.8588075637817383
Execution time: 1.8901219367980957
Execution time: 1.8942387104034424
Execution time: 2.4871997833251953
Execution time: 2.5616471767425537
Execution time: 2.001333475112915
Execution time: 1.8667411804199219
Execution time: 1.8092591762542725
Execution time: 1.9565715789794922
```

Comment: Instead of utilizing saveAsTable, consider creating a table and inserting data into it using insertInto for improved speed, especially from the second attempt onwards. The initial creation of table metadata may take some time during the first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try partitioning:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("date_column").saveAsTable("my_catalog.default.people")
```

or any other column that is suitable for partitioning. (Such as strings as you mentioned)

You can also try `parquet` file format:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").saveAsTable("my_catalog.default.people")
```